# Getting Timeout when connecting to StrongSwan IPSec

Tags: networking, vpn, ipsec, fritzbox, strongswan

I've tried to set up a Root Server in the public Internet with StrongSwan to use it as a VPN Server. Plan is to tunnel all Internet Traffic for some devices via this server. I've also set up an OpenVPN Server for the same which works fine but some devices support IPSec only so I need that as well so please no hints to use OpenVPN instead ;) The issue I'm facing is that communication between client and server is resulting in a timeout independend on what client I use. In the server logs when trying to connect I get a lot of these messages:

```
Feb 22 16:05:30 htzsv001 charon: 14[IKE] retransmit 5 of request with message ID 0
```

While on the client I either get nothing at all or Error 0x2027 which refers to Timeout from what I've found on the Internet. Main Usecase is to connect a FritzBox Router with the VPN so let me show that config here though other configs obviously look different and as I get the issue on all devices I assume it's a more general issue or one with the server config.

Server Config:

```
# ipsec.conf - strongSwan IPsec configuration file
config setup

conn %default
 left=VPN Server fqdn
 leftsubnet=0.0.0.0
 authby=secret
 auto=start

conn avm2swan
 ike=aes256-sha-modp1024
 esp=aes256-sha1-modp1024
 right=DynDNS Of my Home
 rightid=DynDNS Of my Home
 rightsubnet=192.168.0.0/24
 ikelifetime=3600s
 keylife=3600s
```

On the FritzBox I imported the following config:

```
vpncfg {
 connections {
 enabled = yes;
 editable = no;
 conn_type = conntype_lan;
 name = Server fqdn;
 boxuser_id = 0;
 always_renew = yes;
 reject_not_encrypted = no;
 dont_filter_netbios = yes;
 localip = 0.0.0.0;
 local_virtualip = 0.0.0.0;
 remoteip = 0.0.0.0;
 remote_virtualip = 0.0.0.0;
 remotehostname = Server fqdn;
 keepalive_ip = 0.0.0.0;
 localid {
 fqdn = DynDNS Of my Home;
 }
 remoteid {
 fqdn = Server Hostname;
 }
 mode = phase1_mode_idp;
 phase1ss = "all/all/all";
 keytype = connkeytype_pre_shared;
 key = "Password set in ipsec.secrets";
 cert_do_server_auth = no;
 use_nat_t = yes;
 use_xauth = no;
 use_cfgmode = no;
 phase2localid {
 ipnet {
 ipaddr = 192.168.0.0;
 mask = 255.255.255.0;
 }
 }
 phase2remoteid {
 ipnet {
 ipaddr = Server IP;
 mask = 255.255.255.192;
 }
 }
 phase2ss = "esp-all-all/ah-none/comp-all/pfs";
 accesslist = "permit ip any 192.168.0.0 255.255.255.0";
 }
 ike_forward_rules = "udp 0.0.0.0:500 0.0.0.0:500", 
 "udp 0.0.0.0:4500 0.0.0.0:4500";
}
```

The line where I'm absolutely not sure is

```
mask = 255.255.255.192;
```

In phase2remoteid section, I just put the Netmask that ifconfig gives me for the interface on the Server, maybe it shpuld be 0.0.0.0? Everything else looks reasonable to me but maybe I have some bigger misunderstanding here?

Comment: What IKE message is retransmitted there? (i.e. please post more of the log)